# How to sort a column by date added?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I would like to know a simple method to sort a column by date added , for example:

```
ID|Name|Age|Date
1  John 21  20/03/2012
2  Chart 22 21/03/2012
3  Dart  31 22/03/2012
4  Rat   12 23/03/2012
```

So I would like to add a option to sort the column Date date of values , if you know what i mean.

THanks

Comment: A column of the SQL table? or a column of how you are storing the data in a variable, datatable, etc?

Comment: is 'Date' the same as 'Date Added'? What data structures are you using? Does this table live in SQL? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Which technology are you using to pull data from your database? Do you want to sort it at the source or sort it in the UI? Which technology are you using to display your data?

Comment: Yes Sql database , sort it at the UI , I'm using gridview sql data source to display the values

Comment: How are you getting the info back from SQL? Linq2Something, a direct text SQL query, etc?

Comment: I think you're trying to sort the gridview columns. Here's a similar post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138412/how-to-sort-columns-in-an-asp-net-gridview-if-using-a-custom-datasource

Answer (score 5):

Are you trying to use Linq2Sql? If so, you can just do:

```
var result = from x in MyDataTable
             orderby x.Date ascending
             select x;
```

(replace `ascending` by `descending` if you want it to go the other way).

If you would like to optionally sort it, you can use `IQueryable<T>`s and optionally sort, a la:

```
IQueryable<MyDataTable> GetData(bool sortByDate)
{
    var result = from x in DataContext.Table<MyDataTable>
                 where SomeMatchingClause(x)
                 select x;

    if(sortByDate)
    {
        result = result.OrderBy(x => x.Date); // or OrderByDescending
    }

    return result;
}
```

If you're querying in SQL directly, just do

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY Date ASC
```

(replace `ASC` with `DESC` if you want it to go the other way)

I don't frequently build SQL queries as `string`s in C#, but if you wanted to make this optional, I guess you could incrementally build the query, even though it's really gross:

```
string GetSqlQuery(bool sortByDate)
{
    string result = "SELECT * FROM MyTable";
    if(sortByDate)
    {
        result += " ORDER BY Date ASC";
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I used on a button SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY Date ASC , sqlconnect,sqlcommand with the string select and execute scalar. nothing happened

Comment: Did you replace `MyTable` with the actual name of your table? I'm fairly unfamiliar with `SqlConnect` and `SqlCommand`, but it seems like `ExecuteScalar` may not be the correct method to bring back a set of tabular data. Looking at this (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx), it seems like maybe `ExecuteReader` is what you need to do?

Comment: yes , nothing happened , the rows are in the same position . if there's another simple method please explain me how to do it . thank you very much

Comment: This is how you order rows in SQL. It looks like you showed a table whose `Date`s are presorted: change `ASC` to `DESC` and it should show up in the opposite order.

Comment: nothing happened , the rows are in the same position , they need to be arranged by date from Date column

Answer (score 0):

In your SQL query, put order by DATE at the end

Comment: Yes Sql database , sort it at the UI , I'm using gridview sql data source to display the values

Comment: If you have Linq working use eouw0o83hf's answer posted above. Linq lets you sort the data after it comes from the DB meaning you don't have to change your SQL code. If you don't have Linq, you can change your SQL code to sort the data. Hope this helps.